# Captcha or List of questions?

Tags: security, captcha

I recently heard about Captcha the problem of OCS, and someone think that in the future this Human Verification Technical will vanish. So, maybe is best to check if a user is a real human with a list of question?

I think that couldn't be cracked by the bots...but maybe I'm wrong...

Comment: It depends what the questions are...

Comment: A list of question designed to detect humans is a CAPTCHA by definition.

Comment: A list of questions is a "Completely automated test to tell computers and humans apart" or CAPTCHA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that with a list of questions, you have a list...so there's only x questions. Eventually somebody could teach the bots the answers and then what? Nothing...

There's no real answer, since bots can become as strong as whoever builds them wants them to be, but for now ReCAPTCHA will probably be the easiest solution to stop *most* bots (not all, since ReCAPTCHA is cracked too, apparently).

But it is a good thought, and people have considered it, and some people implement it. They're far and wide and the lists aren't really the same, so it wouldn't really be worth it for a bot maker to make a list of answers for a single website. However, if they really want at your site bad enough, they could.

Comment: With regard for your last paragraph, is there any specific reason the bots would be after you, or are they just looking for low-hanging fruit?  Do you have to outrun the bear, or just the guy next to you?

Comment: There's no real reason any bot maker would go after you unless you did something stupid like brag about how your CAPTCHA could stomp out any bot, or if you had a really, really popular site, I suppose. I guess being low ranking has its advantages.

Answer (score 2):

Smashing magazine just did a pretty good article on the different types of captcha systems there are.  Here is the [link to the article](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/03/04/in-search-of-the-perfect-captcha/).  In my opinion, I would avoid a captcha system altogether.

Answer (score 0):

I'd not want to answer a lot of questions, so a captcha might be good enough for a variety of applications. The question is whether the additional security would be worth annoying users.